# Ocaml Stack push creates a type error

Tags: stack, ocaml, typeerror

So in when I try to push to a stack

```
# let s = Stack.create ;;
val s : unit -> 'a Stack.t = <fun>
# Stack.push 1 s ;;
```

in utop or ocaml toplevel i get an error

```
Error: This expression has type unit -> 'a Stack.t
       but an expression was expected of type int Stack.t
```

Why? How should should I do it? There are examples that say this should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Stack.create` is a function that takes a `unit` argument. You are using it as a value, assigining the `create` function to `s`, hence the toplevel printing the type as `val s : unit -> 'a Stack.t = <fun>`.

The correct way to create a stack is with `let s = Stack.create ();;`